# Accessing image with static url link gives FileNotFoundException - android

Tags: android, http, url

I am trying to get the image which has static link and setting it under ImageView. But http gives me exception of File Not Found. Same image I can open in my browser easily and same code works well if image I am trying to access does not have static in url link. Can someone please help how to get the static image url to download\fetch? I am not sure if the issue is because of static or not though.

```
new DownloadImageTask(mImageView)
                .execute("http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg");



private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something related to useragent. It works well with another user agent. 
Try this.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19";
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        System.setProperty("http.agent", ua);
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}
```

Let me know your results.

Comment: Nice .. Maybe it is a kind of protection of this website ..  There are a lot of people trying to get this image .. Check it out in google search ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it's not related to android. I loaded [this](http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif) using the same code :)

Probably they shut down the subdomain static.die.net, die.net is still working.

Comment: static.die.net is working : check this - http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg . It's just when I am trying to load in android it's failing with file not found exception. Is there any direct die.net link for these images?

Comment: All I'm saying is that the image is the problem. wget <same-url> in a terminal also says 404 Not Found. So, its nothing specific to android. UPDATE : hmmn, sorry, my bad - its the user agent thing.